# My site is loading twice when tested with pingdom

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, pingdom

Hi maybe someone can help me?

Upon checking my site (get-a-way.com) with Pingdom my sites seems to be loading twice and adding on about 2 seconds to my load time. I have read through a few related comments and tried to fix it but the problem persists.

I have attached two screen shots that may help

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: > I have attached two screen shots that may help

where?

Comment: I could only share image url. Can you see them?